# Pass a part of link in android app after click over it

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my app manifest i wrote this code to open some links with my app adding the intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

I tried to send via email to myself a link; for example: `http://www.example.com/1234`. click over the link i open the app.. That's great. Now, is it possible take the 1234 part of the link and put it into a textview? Something like:

```
mTextView.setText(textFromLink);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already get access to the URL inside your app? If not, you can get it e.g. in your `onCreate` method with

`Uri link = getIntent().getData();`

which returns a Uri object:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

This object has several methods to get the specific parts of the URL. In your case it will probably be

`String content = link.getLastPathSegment()`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getLastPathSegment()

This returns a string that you can set in your TextView:

`mTextView.setText(content);`

Comment: oook. It works! But only if the link exist.. i mean, if i open the app before click over the link it crashes because the Uri link doesn't exists...

Comment: well done dude. Now it works perfectly with some control! Thank you!

Comment: yep, you'll need to check is getIntent().getData is != null :-)